# How do I block a user from superuser?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, users

Is there a way to block a user I do not want reading my questions?

Comment: "This question does not show research; it is not helpful" I think this applies here.

Comment: okay you can close then. you are right jcole. Now that i know you can't block users, then my question is resolved.

Comment: Kinda defeats the point of a website, kinda.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All content you post is made available under the terms of CC-BY-SA (this is part of the site's [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal), see section 3). That means that your posts will be made available for the public to view. You do not have any control over who can view your posts.

Comment: thank you for a good response.
voted you up and accepted as best answer. your answer makes sense and you didn't include any assumptions or personal feelings. Just facts.

Comment: if we could favorite users, I would favorite you.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot block users from reading your questions.

The underlying issue here (and which may be why you're asking in the first place) is that you're posting questions that are either off topic, not constructive or too localised. This will often lead to them being closed as such.

Please avail yourself of the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) and what type of questions are suited for Super User.

Comment: users like you are who i want to block. how do you know the premise of my question that i did not state? You do not, because you only assumed what, in your twisted ideal of reality, makes sense to you.

Comment: @designerr000 ~ "Users like you are who I want to block" ... who's that now? The moderators? (those are the ones with the diamonds next to their names) ~ Also, you would go a lot further by using proper grammar and the like.

Comment: Thank you for being a part of Super User @des Your recent closed questions list just before the raising of this question leads to strong correlation as to reasoning.

Comment: "moderator" only means you have used the site for awhile. Does not mean you are not wrong

Comment: @designerr000: On the contrary. Moderators are _elected_ by the users on the site. You don't get to be one just for using the site for a while.

Comment: no they aren't "elected". you are automatically given the title when you have enough "points". think again.

Comment: @designerr000 when a moderator is wrong we bring the question to meta (which you have done, correctly, so thank you for doing so) and then we make a logical post which can be correctly addressed (which you seem to have done emotionally, and not as something that can be addressed directly, we are left to guess at why you are upset). Thank you for bringing your complaint to this place, now can you formulate a slightly more coherent reason as to why you are upset with the moderators, who are tasked with keeping the sites in order?

Comment: @designerr000 as far as "they are given the title automatically when they have enough 'points' maybe you would like to read this section? http://superuser.com/about#moderators

Comment: thank you jcole for that information. Keep in mind that if it is an election system, then moderators are essentially a politician -- even more reason why moderators cannot be trusted (although, like in real life, there are a few politicians, or moderators, who are good people and can be trusted).

Comment: on the other hand, i accept not being correct on politicians, er, moderators, not being elected. I see now that they are.

Comment: You are welcome, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Key difference between moderators and politicians: we don't have corporate sponsors, campaign contributions, lobbyists, or all-expenses paid vacations to Hawaii. Or a salary - we're all volunteers. All that aside, we appreciate feedback from users, but your account has a history of low-quality contributions. As random suggested, you should take a good look at the [FAQ] before asking more questions. This site is here to help people, but consistently posting emotionally with feelings, and trying to evade our guidelines on acceptable questions isn't productive for anybody involved.

Comment: In the Wikipedia there are elected and non-payed moderators as well. It is the sheer power that can lead to misuse eg. deleting a lemma. The "relevance criteria" is widely interpreted there. But I don't think this applies here, at least for now.

Comment: Everyone, do remember that the actions of moderators here are quite public: *everyone* of over 10k rep can see *everything* that gets deleted and can easily find them (and all closures, locks, etc) via the site tools that they are provided with. And we then have meta as a publicly available platform to discuss everything - including moderation decisions. It'd be very difficult for a community elected ♦ to go rogue without it being detected very quickly.